For every $k \ge 1$, there exist successive primes $p, q, r$ with $p \ge 5$, and $q - p = r - q$ and $q - p = 6k$.
Today, I delved into prime number relationships and found myself unexpectedly drawn to these questions (@CalvinLin explained that the difference is always divisible by $6$).
I wrote a Python program to identify these prime triplets $(p, q, r)$. With primes up to $10,000,000$, the value of $k$ ranges from $1$ to $10$, taking on all values (but not necessarily in order).
I put down the conjecture tag since I searched and could not find anything on this.

Can you define "successive primes"? IE Are you referring to "Twin primes of difference 6k"?  IE $(5, 11, 17)$ will not satisfy as there are primes 7 and 13 between them.

@CalvinLin just the integer ordering, like $(17, 19, 23)$ which doesn't work for this and $(47, 53, 59)$, which has $k = 1$.

FYI, what you're asking about is a special case of Prime $k$-tuples, where your particular patterns are of the form $(0, 6k, 12k)$. For $k=1$, i.e., $(0, 6, 12)$, it even has a special name of sexy prime triplets. Also note that "It is conjectured that every admissible k-tuple matches infinitely many positions in the sequence of prime numbers". I haven't checked, but there are likely various related posts here which deal with the prime $k$-tuples, including the infinity conjecture.

@JohnOmielan "A Horse by Another Name"  Quarter horse anyone?
